# Regex match after delimiter and find higher number of the match?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, string, match

I have a match equation

```js
function start() {
 
  var str = "10x2+10x+10y100-20y30";
  var match = str.match(/([a-z])=?(\d+)/g);//find the higher value of power only and also print the power value only withput alphapets).i need match like "100"
  
  var text;
  if(match < 10)
    {text = "less 10";}
  else if(match == "10")
    {text == "equal";}
  else
    {text ="above 10";}
  
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML=text;
 }
start();
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

i need match the power values  and also getting out with higher power value only.

example   :`10x2+10y90+9x91  out --> "90"`.
what wrong with my and corret my regex match with suitable format.Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `match` contains all the powers that matches your regex, not just one. You'll have to iterate over them to find the greatest.

I took your code and modified it a bit to work :

```js
function start() {
 
  var str = "10x2+10x+10y100-20y30";
  var match = str.match(/([a-z])=?(\d+)/g);//find the higher value of power only and also print the power value only withput alphapets).i need match like "100"

  var max = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < match.length; i++) { // Iterate over all matches
    var currentValue = parseInt(match[i].substring(1)); // Get the value of that match, without using the first letter
    if (currentValue > max) {
      max = currentValue; // Update maximum if it is greater than the old one
    } 
  }
  
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML=max;
 }
start();
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: In my above code higher power value `100`.but your coding out is ` 30`

Comment: @prasad Sorry, I forgot to use `parseInt();` on line `var currentValue = parseInt(match[i].substring(1));`. It's corrected, and it works, now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const str = '10x2+10x+10y100-20y30'
     ,regex = /([a-z])=?(\d+)/g
const matches = []
let match
while ((match = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  matches.push(match[2])
}
const result = matches.reduce((a, b) => Number(a) > Number(b) ? a : b)
console.log(result)
```